# Mongoose infinite loop on Model creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

### Background

I have  Mongoose Schema about Surveys, that needs to check if the Survey belongs to a set of countries that is in another collection.

### Code

To check this, I have a surveySchema, a countrySchema, and a file where I create the models and connect to the DB.

To perform the check that a survey belongs to a valid country, I am using [Mongoose async validators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) in surveySchema like the following:

**surveySchema.js:**

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const surveySchema = {
    subject: { type: String, required: true },
    country: {
        type: String,
        validate: {
            validator: {
                isAsync: true,
                validator: async function(val, callback) {

                    const {
                        Country
                    } = require("./models.js").getModels();

                    const countriesNum = await Country.find({"isoCodes.alpha2": val}).count();
                    callback(countriesNum === 1);
                }
            },
            message: "The country {VALUE} is not available in the DB at the moment."
        }
    }
};


module.exports = new mongoose.Schema(surveySchema);
module.exports.surveySchema = surveySchema;
```

**countrySchema.js:**

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const countrySchema = {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    isoCodes:{
        alpha2: { type: String, required: true }
        }
    }
};


module.exports = new mongoose.Schema(countrySchema);
module.exports.countrySchema = countrySchema;
```

**models.js:**

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fs = require("fs");

const DB_CONFIG = "./config/dbConfig.json";

/**
 *  Module responsible for initializing the Models. Should be a Singleton.   
 */
module.exports = (function() {
    let models;

    const initialize = () => {

        //Connect to DB
        const {
            dbConnectionURL
        } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(DB_CONFIG, "utf8"));

        mongoose.connect(dbConnectionURL);
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

        //Build Models Object
        models = {
            Country: mongoose.model('Country', require("./countrySchema.js")),
            Survey: mongoose.model('Survey', require("./surveySchema.js"))
        };

    };

    const getModels = () => {
        if (models === undefined)
            initialize();

        return models;
    };

    return Object.freeze({
        getModels
    });
}());
```

The idea here is that I am using the **models.js** file in other places as well. Because this file is also responsible for connecting to the DB, I decided to make it a Singleton. This way, I should only connect once, and all further requests will always return the same Models, which would be ideal.

### Problem

The problem here is that I have a circular dependency that results in:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at exports.isMongooseObject (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:537:12)
```

...

The flow of code leading to this error is:

1. Code runs getModels()`
2. `getModels()` checks that `models` is undefined and runs `initialize()`
3. `initialize()` tries to create the models.
4. When creating the Survey model `Survey: mongoose.model('Survey', require("./surveySchema.js"))` it runs into the `validator` function, which again requires `models.js`
5. Infinite loop begins

### Questions

1. Is there any other way to check if a Survey's country is part of the county's collection without making a async validation?
2. How can I structure/change my code so this doesn't happen?

Comment: Why do you think async validation is not a good approach?

Comment: And your singleton is not working because each time you call `models()`, `let models;` runs. So it's bound to be undefined always. If you take `let models;` outside of `module.exports` it should probably solve this issue.

Comment: I think async validation may not be the answer here because I need to include a model from another schema. As for the `let models` statement, placing it outside the function won't solve the issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, I think you are a bit confused about how you are using your models.js module. I think this is what is happening:

You are exporting a single function from models.js:

**models.js**

```
module.exports = function() { ... };
```

Therefore, when you require it, you just get that single function:

**surveySchema.js**

```
const models = require("./models.js");
```

`models` is now a function. Which means every time you call it, you run through the code in models.js and create a new variable `let models;`, and also new functions `initialize()` and `getModels()`.

You could move the `let models` out of the anonymous function into the global scope which would probably fix it, but for my money you only want to run the anonymous function in models.js once, so I would [invoke it immediately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and set the exports of the module to its result:

**models.js**

```
module.exports = (function() {
    // codez here
    return Object.freeze({
        getModels
    });
})();  // immediately invoke the function.
```

Use it:

```
// models is now the frozen object returned
const { Survey } = models.getModels();
```

As for options to validation, there's no reason why you can't add your own middleware validation code if normal async validation doesn't do it for you using serial or parallel mechanisms as described in [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

#### Update after comments

The second problem as you point out is that during first execution of `getModels() -> initialize()` you call `require('./surveySchema.js')`, but this calls `getModels()` which is still in the process of being called and hasn't yet initialized `models`, so `initialize()` is re-entered.

I think what you're trying to achieve is fine (survey *schema* depends on customer *model*), because you can still draw an object graph without any circular dependencies, and it's just the way you've implemented it that you've ended up with one. The simplest way to deal with this I think is actually to keep the circular reference, but defer the point at which you call `getModels()` in `surveySchema.js`:

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const models = require("./models.js");

const surveySchema = {
    subject: { type: String, required: true },
    country: {
        type: String,
        validate: {
            validator: {
                isAsync: true,
                validator: async function(val, callback) {
                    // !! moved from the global scope to here, where we actually use it  
                    const {
                        Country
                    } = models.getModels();

                     const countries = await Country.find({"isoCodes.alpha2": val});
                     callback(countries.length === 1);
                }
            },
            message: "The country {VALUE} is not available in the DB at the moment."
        }
    }
};

module.exports = new mongoose.Schema(surveySchema);
module.exports.surveySchema = surveySchema;
```

A neater and probably more extensible way of approaching it, though, might be to separate out the connection code from the models code, since it's a different concept altogether.

#### Update #2 after more comments

The infinite stack you're seeing is because you have not used the API correctly. You have:

```
const surveySchema = {
    country: {
        validate: {
            validator: {
                isAsync: true,
                validator: async function(val, callback) {...}
            },
        },
        ...
    }
};
```

You should have:

```
const surveySchema = {
    country: {
        validate: {
            isAsync: true,
            validator: async function(val, callback) {...}
        },
        ...
    }
};
```

As per [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators).

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough. As someone who is asking here for help, I take it upon myself to completely understand and test every advice given to me. When I said your suggestion didn't work, I meant that I had tested it, and that it didn't work =(

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your suggestion, but as I said, it still wont work because the variable `models` is still always `undefined`.

Comment: Are you sure that the code gets to the `models = {...` line in models.js the first time and before you call `.getModels()` the second time?

Comment: Good Point. So the code flow runs `models.js` to create the models. However, inside `models.js` I try to create the **Survey schema**, which has a call to `const { Country } = models.getModels();`, which in turn tries to run the `models.js` file again. However, the file is still trying to create the models from the first time, and so in this second run, the variable `models` will obviously be `undefined`. I am pretty much running in to a loop here. This is an architectural problem to which I have no solution yet .... perhaps I should update my question? I am lost on how to fix this here...

Comment: Well, If I do it like you suggest, I get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. This happens even when I am defining `const { Country }...` inside the validator function. This means that I likely have an infinite recursion between the Survey and Models, which strengthens the idea that using an `async` validator is not the way to go here :S

Comment: I now present the issue in a different way. Hopefully this is more clear :S

Comment: I have spotted another issue and have updated my answer.

Comment: Jesus Christ (how could I not see that ?) ..... this is what happens when you code without sleep. Or coffee. Or both. You Sir, deserve your bounty.